# $m$ players choosing from $n$ integers game

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, combinatorial-game-theory

$m$ players play a game in which they pick distinctive integers in the range $0:n$ one after another. Then we pick a random integer from $0:n$. Whoever is closest to our pick wins.

What's the optimal strategy for the first player? Is there an algorithmic way to solve this problem other than an exhaustive search?

Comment: Generally games with more than two players are impossible to analyze because of the possibility of collusion between the players.  It is not clear what each player's objective is.  If you declare what strategy each player is using you can sometimes get there.  Here whatever the first player picks the next two could pick the number above and the number below, leaving the first player only $\frac 1{n+1}$ chance of winning.

Comment: As the game is described, re the comment of @RossMillikan, there is no way to keep the first player's pick secret, because the game requires that each player pick a number that no one else has picked.  The player can't do that without knowing the previous picks.  An attempt may be made to preserve the **distinct** numbers constraint, and still *reduce* collusion possibilities by keeping the numbers secret and employing an *umpire*.  Then things get more complicated.  See, for example, [Kriegspiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegspiel_(chess)).